# HTML/CSS - Strange resizing?

Tags: html, css, window, size

I'm making a website but I want it to resize when I change my window size.

So I did everything in percentages.

Can someone explain why it's still behaving so weird, and how to fix it?

Code:
http://pastebin.com/JUB6Zvri

Comment: whats behaving strangely?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using margin for left , right , top and bottom use only left , right , top and bottom properties

Look what i did

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <head>
        <style type="text/css">
html {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #272C34;
        margin: 0%;
        padding: 0%;
}

body{
        height: 100%;
        position: static;
        margin: 0%;
        padding: 0%;
}

#whitetop {
        width: 100%;
        height: 4%;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #E8E8E7;
        top: 10%;
       left: 0%;
        right: 0%;
        bottom: -10%;
        padding: 0%;
        z-index: 1;
}

#whitebot {
        width: 100%;
        height: 30%;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #E8E8E7;
        top: 32%;
        left: 0%;
        right: 0%;
        bottom: -32%;
        padding: 0%;
        z-index: 1;
}

#earth {
        width: 100%;
        height: 20%;
        position: absolute;
       top: 10%;
        left: 0%;
        right: 0%;
        bottom: -10%;
        z-index: 0;
}

        </style>
                <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
                <title>Home</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <div id="whitetop">
                </div>
                <div id="whitebot">
                </div>
                <img src="earth2.jpg"/ id="earth">
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried that, but then everything looks weird..

Comment: hmm . Then take a look at media queries here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp hope it will help

Comment: @SanderSpoelstra can you explain *what* is behaving so weird?

Comment: Think I fixed it already.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at CSS media queries.

Basic idea of resizing is: screens with a width more than 960 = PC, 960 and lower are considered a mobile or iPad...

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) { 
    From this point you start making everything in % for the mobiles and iPads
}
```